# How to do network tracing in Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having a problem with a third-party library. It worked last week but this week is failing. I wish to turn on the network tracing as I would normally configure in web.config such as is described for an Azure App Services job here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/03/14/how-to-get-a-system-net-trace-of-your-c-web-job/

Is this in any way possible with Azure Functions, or is there an alternative?

Comment: You can't edit `web.config` for functions

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm asking what would be the equivalent for setting up network tracing in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with consumption plan as we don't allow you to modify the web.config.

If you can set up an app service plan for testing, you can deploy the functions runtime as a private site extension with your web.config changes, see here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#deployment

A related option to help you with diagnostics/analytics is the preview app insights support: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights-Early-Preview